# Capturing a video and uploading it to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, video-streaming, blob, azure-media-services

I am working on a sample project where I want to capture video from a webcam and upload it directly to the blob without saving the video locally.

It should work in a such a way that it should not store the video locally. Is there any way to keep uploading the video source streaming that is being captured to Blob storage in parallel?

Comment: One thing you could look at is Azure Media Services: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/media-services/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically this should be possible. Blob Storage allows you to upload your file in chunks and once you're done you can commit these chunks in a specific order:

- [PutBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblock.aspx): Upload a chunk
- [PutBlockList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblocklist.aspx): Commit a list of chunks in a specific order

With these methods you can for example create a buffer in memory which stores the video and call PutBlock each time the buffer reaches a certain size. Then, once the recording is done you can call PutBlockList to commit all blocks. As a result, your blob will contain the complete recording without saving it to local disk first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir. One more question, how can we achieve video recording in to chunks from silverlight application that captures videos from video source?