# Capture webcamera and save into azure blob storage using UWP C# (mediaCapture)

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-blob-storage, mediacapture

I have UWP C# app which should record video from webcamera.

Once user hits 'Start Record' I should capture video and save into azure blob storage. So for capturing the webcamera I use mediaCapture.

At this moment I can save into local storage using the following code

```
// Create storage file for the capture
var videoFile = await _captureFolder.CreateFileAsync("SimpleVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
var encodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
// Calculate rotation angle, taking mirroring into account if necessary
var rotationAngle = CameraRotationHelper.ConvertSimpleOrientationToClockwiseDegrees(_rotationHelper.GetCameraCaptureOrientation());
encodingProfile.Video.Properties.Add(RotationKey, PropertyValue.CreateInt32(rotationAngle));

Debug.WriteLine("Starting recording to " + videoFile.Path);

await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(encodingProfile, videoFile);
_isRecording = true;

Debug.WriteLine("Started recording!");
```

However my goal is to start upload into Azure blob using Azure.Storage.Blobs directly without saving in local machine.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

**Blob Storage allows you to upload your file in chunks [spliting file in smaller size] and once you're done you can commit these chunks in a specific order:**

Try with these methods ,

1. [Put Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblock?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)   : **Upload a chunk**.
2. [PutBlockList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.putblocklist?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)  : **Commit a list of chunks in a specific order**

With these methods you can for example create a buffer in memory which stores the video and call `PutBlock` each time the buffer reaches a certain size. Then, once the recording is done you can call `PutBlockList` to commit all blocks. As a result, your blob will contain the complete recording without saving it to local disk first.

How to use these methods refer this [document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/windows-azure-blockblob-putblock-method/) and [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191777/capturing-a-video-and-uploading-it-to-azure-blob)

Comment: The question is about uploading data into blob storage without saving it locally when using media APIs in UWP applications.